# How to test a class having only variable definitions?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have a class that only contains the definition of final strings. As everything is static and there are no methods, how can I test this code ?

```
public static myErrorClass{
    public static final String ERROR_NO_FILE_SELECTED = system.label.NTProject_NoImportXMLFilesSelected; 
    public static final String ERROR_EMPTY_XML = system.label.NTProject_TheProjectCannotBeNull;   
    public static final String ERROR_INVALID_XML = system.label.NTProject_ImportFailed;    
    public static final String ERROR_FILESIZE_TOO_LARGE = system.label.NTProject_TheXMLFileIsTooLarge;    
}
```

Comment: Hi! Please edit your question to provide more information related to your question. As it stands now, this will get closed pretty quickly as "unclear what you are asking".

Comment: welcome to salesforce.stackexchange user8254, as Jesse noted, questions only asked in the title may go unnoticed. Only posting code without much text on what you've tried, are having trouble with or can't get to work can be hard to understand. By providing more details and context, you can help us help you.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I believe that salesforce is clever enough to know that this class doesn't require test code and it's not included in the code coverage calculation. This may however not show, and I have no official reference of this.

If you want to be absurdly thorough, you can do:

```
System.assertEquals(system.label.NTProject_NoImportXMLFilesSelected,
                         myErrorClass.ERROR_NO_FILE_SELECTED);
```

Besides code coverage you should also consider the functional aspects and to what extend that should be tested.